# SKSafariViewController Not opening Protected pdf in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a RMS Protected pdf file something like 'sample.ppdf'.
Its being loaded from an URL.

Now When I implement the following :
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(_documentUrl));

iPhone Safari App opens and asks me for an option to open with a particular App 'AIP Viewer'

Now when i try implementing the same with the following code :

```
    SFSafariViewController *svc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
svc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

SKSafariViewController opens but is Blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*! @abstract Returns a view controller that loads a URL.
    @param URL the initial URL to navigate to. Only supports initial URLs with http:// or https:// schemes.
 */
- (instancetype)initWithURL:(NSURL *)URL;
```

Make sure you url is  http://*** or https://***

Answer (score 0):

`SFSafariViewController` is compatible with version `iOS 9.0+`. Put the version check if the `iOS version` is lesser than `iOS 9.0` open it directly in safari browser.

**Try this,**

```
NSURL *urlAsString = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your_URL"]];

 if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil)  {

   SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:urlAsString];

   [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];

} 
else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlAsString];

}
```